# How to read in csv files with quotation marks using read.csv.sql

Tags: r, sqldf

When converting data to csv Excel normally encloses categorical variables which contain commas in quotation marks. For example: \"MÃ‰******, ****¿.

When using the `read.csv.sql` function, I'm having huge issues with handling the commas, and the execution of the code get frequently halted due to this.

When using the `read.csv` function I don't have this problem, and this is because of the way the function uses the quote argument.

Does Anyone know how to replicate the same behaviour with `read.csv.sql`?

Comment: You can preprocess your input using the `filter` argument of `read.csv.sql`  Search for the word filter on the home page for several examples -- https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

Comment: I've tried the documentation, data show commas within strings in this way: ,\"JAY, DOREEN A\". If I filter using the example in the documentation: filter = "gawk -v osep=; -f csv.awk" (I know it may not be right) I get the following error: "'gawk' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". In in a windows environment.

Comment: You have to have installed the software you references in `filter`.  Most UNIX systems will have `gawk`, `awk` or some variation already or else you can install it yourself and Rtools ( https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ ) has `gawk` on Windows.